# What is the recommended logic to use when checking authenticity in Auto Renewal Subscriptions

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app where I’m offering `Auto Renewal Subscriptions`. Here is how it currently works, when the user subscribes, it saves a `Bool` in `UserDefaults` as `true`, after that I can make a receipt request to see if the subscription has expired. My issue or what I don’t fully understand is the logic on how often to make that request, checking for authenticity every time the user launches the app seems like a lot, or do I need to save the expiration date in `UserDefaults` and just check a couple of days after the expiration date to see if the user renewed? This way we limit the requests we make to retrieve the Apple receipt.

Can someone share the logic used when checking for authenticity in an app using Auto Renewal Subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

The "right" way to do it is to manage everything server side (with some caching on the device in case the user is offline). Refreshing the receipt on the device is insecure, slow, and could make that annoying "Login with iTunes" prompt keep popping up for the user :)

It also prevents you from ever having complete analytics of your subscriber base since you can only get data points when they are active in the app.

What you would do is store the receipt file in a database after purchase, and refresh it *there* to keep the subscription status up-to-date. Then your app is asking your database if the user is subscribed (and caching the value in UserDefaults).

Here is a good blog post that outlines what the setup should look like: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Comment: I know that doing this on the server would be the best option but at the moment I'll will try the on-device method since I struggled enough getting it to work to introduce a more complicated process. Eventually I will try to implement that on the server. Thanks a lot for your comments and for the link. Do you know of any tutorial that shows how to do that on the server?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials for a complete server option, it can get pretty complex once you get past receipt-validation and basic status tracking. The company I work for provides an out-of-the-box IAP server that may be something to consider: https://www.revenuecat.com

Comment: I was reading the documentation and Revenuecat seems like a nice and simple to use service. Quick question, if understand it correctly and based on the documentation, when using Revenuecat, you don't have to save your Product ID or anything in UserDefaults, you would simply call the `Purchases.shared.makePurchase` and the `Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo` methods, correct? Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre that's correct. RevenueCat automatically manages the cache for you.

Comment: @ enc_life Sounds really simple to be true. One more thing, based on the pricing shown on the website, it looks like you don't get charged until the app makes $10,000 a month correct?

Comment: @fs_tigre correct, the core functionality which includes the complete IAP server is free for your first $10K/mo.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will give it a try.